# Web Application Integration with other applications

Tags: php, wordpress, web-applications, phpbb

I have a web application that requires

1. Blog
2. Forum
3. Chat support etc

Now my web application have different functionality but these above are additional value added services that we provide integrated with our application.

I do not want to write application for them but rather use standard application like wordpress for blog, phpBB for forum, crafty for live chat support.

Is there any way in which I have use common database and interface to provide such functionality with-in an web application via integration.

Typically I want when user A is registered in my app, he will be a user for all the other applications also and can access all functionality with common log in & session.

Note: My application is developed using java, struts2, spring etc while these apps are in php mostly.

Comment: +1 i have the same question while before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a PHPBB chat plugin for the PHPBB forum, and then integrate the PHPBB with wordpress, using wordpress plugin. There are few wordpress plugins to integrate with PHPBB forum.

If you are not limited to PHPBB, you will find many wordpress plugins to integrate with different PHP based forums, such as mybb, pressbb etc.
This way you can integrate all three components together.

Comment: Ok Great. This information is very useful. But again main question is how I integrate these all with any other app, so that users of that app can access all these features seamlessly. And Also installation of MY_WEB_APP will install all other dependencies which have explicit access to them using my_web_app only. HOW?

Comment: @Amol Ghotankar Please check the BBPress forum, it is from the wordpress team, and it integrates best with the wordpress. The bbpress can share user data with an existing WordPress database. Here you can find very good documentation: http://bbpress.org/documentation/integration-with-wordpress/ The integration process is very simple. If this question solved your problem, please mark it accepted. Thanks.